# Are there any actors besides Sean Bean who were in both Game of Thrones and The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes, actors

I'm a big fan of both Game of Thrones TV show and The Lord of the Rings movie trilogy and I really want to know if there is any actors who appeared in both of them, because I haven't noticed anyone except for Sean Bean, who played Eddard 'Ned' Stark in GoT and Boromir in LOTR.

Comment: If you include the Hobbit films, Conan Stevens was both the original Gregor Clegane and he played an orc in the Hobbits

Comment: I knew that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but I loved the Sean Bean got to try and explain what the Council of Elrond was to the NASA press liaison in the movie "the Martian."

Answer (score 17):

No. IMDb has a feature that lets you check for people credited in two separate productions. Sean Bean is the only actor that *Game of Thrones* and any of the *Lord of the Rings* movies have in common, though there are several stunts and effects people who worked on both.

[GoT and Fellowship of the Ring](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0120737,tt0944947)

[GoT and The Two Towers](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0167261,tt0944947)

[GoT and Return of the King](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0167260,tt0944947)

Answer (score 12):

As an addendum to Tooth's resourceful find:

### [Peter Jackson's Hobbit I and Game of Thrones](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0903624,tt0944947)

- [Conan Stevens](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1947403/), GoT: Gregor "The 
  Mountain" Clegane for season 1. PJH1: Bolg the Orc

[image]

- *[Philip Arditti](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1787364/), GoT: Goat Herder 4x06, PJH: **(crew)** Script Reader/Story Analyst*

### [Hobbit II](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt1170358,tt0944947)

(various crew)

### [Hobbit III](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt2310332,tt0944947)

- Conan Stevens, as above, and again in PJH3: Keeper of the Dungeons
- [Chris Reilly](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2687517/), GoT 2x10 "Soldier Tom", 4x01 "Morgan". PJH3: Dwarf Lieutenant (uncredited)

Comment: This might seem like a minor quibble, but the question asked about *Lord of the Rings* trilogy, not the *Hobbit* trilogy.

Answer (score 4):

[**Royd Tolkien**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1596668/) played credited characters in both an episode of *Game of Thrones* (*GoT: Hardhome*) and in the film *The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King*

<sub>**'Gondorian Ranger'**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**'Wildling'**</sub>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Robert Aramayo](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm7075019/filmotype/actor?ref_=m_nmfm_1) is credited as Elrond in  *The Rings of Power* and as Young Ned in *Game of Thrones*.

Comment: I do not recall any such character nor is there any credits on any of Hugo Weaving's profiles for that supposed role.

Comment: @Aegon I think Laura is referring to actor who plays Elrond in Rings of Power

Comment: @fez Note that the scope of this question was the *LotR* trilogy; the question didn't even include *The Hobbit* movies even though the question was posted years later than those movies were released.

Comment: @DavidW On the other hand, there *is* a highly upvoted answer referring to the Hobbit films ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor People can't read.  What's new?

Comment: @DavidW That's an uncharitable interpretation. It *is* an interesting addendum to see if any actors appeared in both the GoT legendarium and the LotR legendarium.

Comment: "Interesting addendum" => comment or new question.